# Unable to send SMS to my India number using Twilio Shortcode

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, twilio-api

I have written following code to send SMS from Twilio using Messaging Service:

```
var message = MessageResource.Create(to: new PhoneNumber("+9198XXXXXXX9"),
body: "This is a test message",
messagingServiceSid: "<<Messaging service id of the service configured at Twilio>>",
);
```

We have purchased a short code with US number and configured that short code to use as a from number for the Messaging service.

However, we are unable to receive SMS at any India number.
We can receive SMS at US number. Our product is having customer-base from number of countries, so we are very much concerned if the short code numbers send SMS to US only.

Any idea or guidance on this will be very much helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You can not send SMS outside US using US short code.

Comment: Either you have to get short code for India or you get normal numbers twilio. Those numbers will be US but they can send SMS all over the world

Comment: The issue with the normal numbers is that they are bound to be marked as spam by carriers in case of volume transaction. That is why we opted for short code. we can buy for India, but there are number of countries (like, China, Australia, UK, France, Germany, Japan, etc) where our customers are based. Do we need to purchase short code for each country?

Comment: If you do not want your numbers to be marked as spammers then yes you need short codes for each country. You can also opt for having multiple numbers from twilio and select randomly to send SMS to countries other than US. I am using the same approach and it is working well for me. None of my 20 twilio numbers are marked as spammer. And I have been sending SMS all over the world. How much is the SMS volume you have?

Comment: We are expecting around 1 million (or more) SMS per month (as our product has email capability and it sends more than 2 million of emails per month on an average). Twilio doesn't mention how to buy short code for countries other than US, UK and Canada.

Comment: You need to get in touch with twilio support or any account manager if you have assigned any.... https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in

Comment: 1.7 Mil SMS per month is not blocking any of my numbers so far.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I would recommend, as Chetan did, to get in touch with [Twilio sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) about this. They can make suggestions about short codes and other ways of sending messages. It is absolutely the case that you can only send messages to US numbers with a US  short code, so you need another option here.